# How do I recursively nest smarty {foreach} loops while still being able to use {$smarty.foreach.<loopName>.first/last}?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a Smarty template file in which I'm looping over hierarchical data represented by nested arrays.  The child data is represented exactly the same way as the parent data, so I wanted to recursively `{include}` the Smarty template to render this:

**Source of "my.tpl"**:

```
{foreach from=$children item="child" name="childrenLoop"}
    {* display stuff here *}
    {if $smarty.foreach.childrenLoop.last}
        {* do something special here when it is the last item *}
    {/if}

    {assign var="grandChildren" value=$child->getChildren()}
    {if $grandChildren|@count > 0}
        {include file="my.tpl" children=$grandChildren}
    {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

My problem is that when the `{include}` finishes executing, `$smarty.foreach.childrenLoop.*` tells me about the `{include}'s` loop, not the current loop.  So if the inner loop had 10 items and the outer loop has 5, `{$smarty.foreach.childrenLoop.total}` will be 10 when I exit the inner loop, rather than 5.  Needless to say, this is messing up my output.

I thought I could get around this problem by suffixing the loop with a value passed along by the include.  I seem to be able to name the loop correctly:

```
{foreach from=$children item="child" name="childrenLoop_`$suffix`"}
```

... but I can't figure out how to access its properties, and the Smarty manual is not helpful:

```
{$smarty.foreach.childrenLoop_$suffix.total} {* NOPE! *}
{$smarty.foreach[childrenLoop_$suffix].total} {* NOPE! *}
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
{assign var="chSuffix" value="childrenLoop_$suffix"}
{foreach from=$children item="child" name="$chSuffix"}
    {$smarty.foreach.$chSuffix.total}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered saving the entire naming convention into a variable.

I had to make a small correction ( the correct syntax is {assign var="chSuffix" value="childrenLoop_$suffix"} ), but it worked!  Thanks!!!

Can you please edit your post with the correct syntax?